# PHPExcel constant '@' symbol at my formula

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a issue when use PHPExcel.
I add formula to a cell and return for client, but my formula constant '@' symbol when return for client even though it's not in my code.

```
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', "=OFFSET(setting!A3,0,0,COUNTA(setting!A:A)-1,1)");

// end of process
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($excel)->disableCalculationCache();
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($excel)->clearCalculationCache();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');
// $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas();
ob_end_clean();
$file_name = 'name';
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

[My formula constant @ symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vba1n.png)

I tried use setPreCalculateFormulas function, but it not working!
thanks for read my issue!

Comment: This sounds more a problem related to the reference to `settings` Can you share the XLSX you use as source for settings?

Comment: Oh, I forgot, PHPExcel is **deprecated** you should switch to **phpoffice/phpspreadsheet**

Comment: oh, really, I'll give it a try. thanks you so much @AndreaOlivato